# Marklogic reference for developers need to check

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

Using MLCP copy mode trying to copy data from DEV env to UAT.

Comment: Please read: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to format your question better. and/or: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: When you are editing the post for clarity. I suggest that you also include the execute privileges attached to "sys-il-wds-u" since the error suggests that you are missing some permissions needed for what you are trying to do.  (8001->security->users->sys-il-wds-u->describe (permissions section)

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you that the user that you are using does not have the necessary privileges to perform the work.

On the target server (the one you are trying to copy data into), ensure that the user account has a [role](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/role#chapter) assigned that has the `xdbc:insert-in` [Execute Privilege](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/exec_privs)